# i have a problem with assigning a letter to char variable of a struct using function

Tags: c, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to assign a letter to a char variable of a struct but I'm getting garbage output, I don't know why such a simple code doesn't work. I couldn't find any answers on the internet

I've already to use `strcpy` or just `scanf` but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct test
{
    int age;
    char name[15];

};
void reg(struct test a)
{
    //scanf("%s",&a.name);
    //strcpy(a.name,"Eldar");
}
int main()
{
    struct test el,*elp;
    elp=&el;
    reg(el);
    printf("%s",el.name);
}
```

I'm getting a weird symbols but not my letter

Comment: sorry if didn't explain my problem properly, my english is very bad:(

Comment: it does work with array of struct but how to do it without array?

Answer (score 6):

You are passing the struct by value. To change the struct in the function, you need to pass the address of the struct. See code below.

```
void reg(struct test *a)
{
    scanf("%s",a->name);
}
int main()
{
    struct test el,*elp;
    elp=&el;
    reg(elp);  // or reg(&el);
    printf("%s",el.name);
}
```